# Does AWS API Gateway enable https by default?

Tags: http, https, aws-api-gateway

How to ensure all inbound requests made through aws api gateway are safe and using https/tls protocol ? I heard that aws api gateway enable https by default but when I test my request as a simple `http` request, that just executes normally.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/faqs/ *"all of the APIs created with Amazon API Gateway expose HTTPS endpoints only. Amazon API Gateway does not support unencrypted (HTTP) endpoints"* - what request specifically are you executing?

Comment: I created several endpoints in my app for testing purposes and integrated them with AWS API Gateway, however when I use aws api gateway endpoint with just `http` that works just as with `https`.